# Empty cell in csv not detected in python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, missing-data

I'm already using `.isna` and `.isnull` to check for missing value in my data and it shows that there is no missing value in the data. But when I skimming the data using excel, I found several empty cells in a column. That column was supposed to have numerical data type, but it got identified as object because it has several empty cells. If I want  to delete these cells, what should I do?

Comment: Can’t you just post a data sample ? df.head(30) or something appropriate ? No one can help you if we can’t have a genuine look at your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That column was supposed to have numerical data type, but it got identified as object because it has several empty cells.

This suggest that they are empty strings, `''`. You could replace them with NaN values using `replace`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it didnt work

Comment: @undernoob maybe it's white space? See if `import string; df[df.isin(list(string.whitespace))].count().sum()` returns a value different from 0

Comment: @undernoob or if `df[particular_column].str.contains('|'.join(string.whitespace)).sum()` returns a value different from 0